# Setting IOCP thread count int .NET Core

Tags: .net-core

In classic .NET I use IOCP for high performance sockets as follows:

```
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out int minWorkerThreads, out int minCompletionPortThreads);
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(minWorkerThreads, Math.Max(16, minCompletionPortThreads));
```

.NET Core does not expose these methods and it has a significant impact on my socket performance.

Is there a workaround or is this being addressed in a future release of .NET core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GetMinThreads`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(Int32,Int32)) and [`SetMinThreads`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(Int32,Int32)) are coming back in the upcoming .Net Core 2.0 and .Net Standard 2.0.

In the meantime, the methods exist on .Net Core 1.x, but are not exposed. This means you can use reflection to call them:

```cs
delegate void GetMinThreadsDelegate(out int workerThreads, out int completionPortThreads);
delegate bool SetMinThreadsDelegate(int workerThreads, int completionPortThreads);

…

var getMinThreads = (GetMinThreadsDelegate)typeof(ThreadPool).GetMethod("GetMinThreads")
    .CreateDelegate(typeof(GetMinThreadsDelegate));
var setMinThreads = (SetMinThreadsDelegate)typeof(ThreadPool).GetMethod("SetMinThreads")
    .CreateDelegate(typeof(SetMinThreadsDelegate));

getMinThreads(out int minWorkerThreads, out int minCompletionPortThreads);
setMinThreads(minWorkerThreads, Math.Max(16, minCompletionPortThreads));
```

This code seems to work fine for me on .Net Core 1.x on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. You'll have to verify yourself if it actually improves performance, especially considering that Unix operating systems do not have IOCPs.

Comment: I haven't spent a lot of time benchmarking this but initial testing shows that this does improve performance on Windows 10. In fact Microsoft has the same code in their Azure IOT gateway adapter. I have not tried the above code on any other OS.